# Long AJAX request in Rails returns `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on Nginx and Passenger

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, nginx, passenger

I have a Rails 3 application that kicks off a AJAX request to get a HTML partial with some expensive, calculated values. This speeds up the actual page load and allows the expensive partial load to happen after the main page has loaded.

This works just fine under most situations, taking anywhere from 5 seconds to 45 seconds to complete. The AJAX request gets completed and the partial gets plopped into the page as expected.

However, on some of the larger Accounts that have more data it takes upwards of 70 or 80 seconds to complete.

In **development** this is no problem. It takes a while, but when it finishes, the partial gets loaded onto the page.

In **staging**, which is essentially a cloned version of Production with minimal infrastructure (no HAProxy Load Balancer and a single, shared server for both web and db), it works fine.

In **production** the request does not complete and instead returns a `err_empty_response`. However, with smaller Accounts that have less data, it does work fine. It's only with these larger accounts that this error is returned.

I have tried nailing down what the issue could be but can't seem to get it working.

Some things that I have tried without success:

- Increase `keepalive_timeout` in nginx config.
- Scale up server in case it was a memory limit.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see anything in nginx error logs?

Comment: @UtsavKesharwani Nope, nothing.